# Powershell Prefix every filename with the directory name it resides in

Tags: powershell

Just like the subject says, I need to rename every file in a folder by prefixing the directory name. I tried this but it seems to process each file over and over until an error occurs

```
gci | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " " + $_.Name}
```

Ideally, I would like this to work recursively

TIA

Comment: if you wrap your `G-CI` call in parens, it will grab all the files ONCE and then feed them into the pipeline one-at-a-time. you can also use the `-File` and the `-Recurse` parameters to make the `G-CI` call grab all the files in the whole dir tree while leaving out the dirs.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Please convert your comments into an answer (comments may be deleted)

Comment: @DavidPostill - thank you for the suggestion ... done! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

one problem with using `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item` in a pipeline is that the `G-CI` call keeps grabbing files from the same dir ... and will often see the renamed file as a file that has not yet been fed into the pipeline.

that can end up with the same file being acted on multiple times. [*grin*]

the solution to that is to wrap the `G-CI` call in parens so that it grabs all the files at one time and *then* feeds them one-at-a-time to the pipeline.

also, you can use the `-File` parameter of `G-CI` to avoid the `Where-Object` filter you have in your code.

also also, you can use the `-Recurse` parameter of `G-CI` to go thru the whole dir tree.

that leads me to the following code.

yours ...

```
gci | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " " + $_.Name}
```

my version of yours ...

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse) |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + ' ' + $_.Name}
```

---

a few other changes that seem worthwhile to me ...

- specify a path in the `G-CI` call
  i am wary of depending on what the OS or PoSh may consider the "current dir". [*grin*]
- build the new file name with something that feels more robust to me
  i would pro'ly use the `-f` string format operator to build the string instead of the sometimes iffy `+` concatenation operator.